# Can't post in a specific Yammer's group

Tags: rest, curl, office365, yammer

I'm doing a curl to send a POST in my group, and it doesn't works, it posts on the All Company Network even if I sent the group_id.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTHTOKENHERE" -X POST -d '{"activity":{"actor":{"email":"MYEMAIL"},"action":"create"}}' https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?body=TestingfromYammersAPI&group_id=GROUPID
```

I'm writing the right group_id, and still not reading that argument.
Does anyone has this problem too?

Yammer's API docs:
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't quoting the URL -___-

Working code:

```
curl -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'authorization: Bearer OAUTHTOKENHERE' -H 'content-type: application/json' -X POST -d ' ' 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?body=MESSAGE_HERE&group_id=GROUP_ID'
```